# Как на javascript обрезать ссылку?

Tags: javascript

Получаю ссылку таким образом

```
var profilePhoto = window.content.document.getElementById('profile_photo_link');
```

В `profilePhoto` попадает такая запись `https://vk.com/photo11792890_264692886`
Как мне обрезать эту часть `https://vk.com/` Пробовал делать replace но ничего у меня не получается, ребята, помогите найти решение.

Comment: В `profilePhoto` не может попадать такая "запись". "Пробовал делать replace но ..." - покажите, как пробовали.

Comment: Пробую сделать так
profilePhoto = window.content.document.getElementById('profile_photo_link');
profilePhoto = profilePhoto.substr(15, profilePhoto.length);
alert(profilePhoto);
Но так и нечего не получается, но если поместить в переменную обичный текст то режет

Comment: `profilePhoto` - это не строка, а DOM элемент. `profilePhoto = profilePhoto.src.substr(15, profilePhoto.length); alert(profilePhoto);`

Comment: Нет, не работает, а может бить из за слешов с точками которые попадают в profilePhoto

Comment: работает, Вы неправильно скопировали мой код

Comment: Мой код
var profilePhotoElement = window.content.document.getElementById('profile_photo_link'); 
var profilePhoto = profilePhotoElement.href.substr(15, profilePhoto.length); 
alert(profilePhoto);

Все верно, какого черта он не работает? Это я для макроса пробую написать. Матерится TypeError: profilePhoto is undefined, line 2 (Error code: -991)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "https://vk.com/photo11792890_264692886";
var res = str.split("com/")
console.log(res[1]) //photo11792890_264692886
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
var str = "https://vk.com/photo11792890_264692886";
var result = str.match( /https:\/\/vk.com\/(\w+)/i );
alert(result[1]);
```

Comment: Четко Ваш пример работает, но если вместо str подставляю свою переменную то не работает.

Comment: @Анатолий, как было сказано в комментариях к вопросу: profilePhoto - это не строка, а DOM элемент.

Comment: @Анатолий, получите строкове значение из вашей переменной и подставляйте.

Comment: @Klym это так String(profilePhoto);  а потом уже остальные манипуляции?

Comment: @Анатолий, нет, `profilePhoto.innerHTML` или `profilePhoto.innerText`

Comment: не пойму за что парню минусов наставили... для конкретного примера у него верный результат.